# Not able to route to children in lazy loading module

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I am fresh developer to angular 4. In one of my project, I am using lazy loading for routing. The lazy loading module contains children component. However, routing to children component is always failing with an error.

```
 Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home/addGroup'
```

Could you help, if I am doing something wrong? I tried in all the ways, but none of them resulted success.

Below are my modules and routing.

index.html:

```html
<app-root></app-root>
```

app.module:

```
import { routes } from './app.routes';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        UserSignupComponent,
        UserLoginComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        routes,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule
    ]
});
```

app.routes:

```
import { HomeModuleModule } from './home-module/home-module.module';

export const appRoutes: Routes = [

    { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'login', component: UserLoginComponent },
    {
        path: 'home', loadChildren: './home-module/home-module.module#HomeModuleModule'
    }
];

export const routes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

app.component.html:

```html
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

homemodule:

```
import { routes } from './home.routes';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        BrowserModule,
        routes,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule
    ],

    declarations: [HomeComponent, AddGroupComponent, AddItemComponent],
    providers: [httpserviceClass, sharedserviceClass],
})
```

home.routes:

```
export const router: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    {
        path: 'home', component: HomeComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'addItem/:groupName', component: AddItemComponent },
            { path: 'addGroup', component: AddGroupComponent },
        ]
    }
];

export const routes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(router);
```

home.component.html:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default noMargin">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Budget</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li> <a [routerLink]="['addGroup']"> addgroup </a>         </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

The point is, I am able to redirect to "home" component of home-module from login component by

> "this.router.navigate(['home']);"

However, from home component, I am not able to route to addGroup component via

```html
<a [routerLink]="['addGroup']"> addgroup </a>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try to remove bracket from routerLink ? Like this : <a routerLink="addGroup">

Comment: Yes, I tried it. But had the same result. 
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home/addGroup'

Comment: Try adding full path to the `routerLink` in `HomeComponent` - `[routerLink]="['home', 'addGroup']"`

Comment: @ManojChalode: I missed to tell. It worked in that way. But I saw 2 problems in it.
1. the url is showing as "http://localhost:4200/home/home/addGroup". path is containing 'home' 2 times. I feel, it should be shown in that way. It should show as "http://localhost:4200/home/addGroup". Is it not?
2. If I have 10 routerLinks,  I have to give 'home' in all the routes unnecessarily?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. I must admit that my understanding was wrong at the time when I posted the question.

I have to mention few points here.

I am routing to homeModule using the route "home" as in *app.routes*.

```
{ path: 'home', loadChildren: './home-module/home-module.module#HomeModuleModule' }
```

And in *home.routes*, I am loading "HomeComponent" as default. Hence routing to "HomeComponent" was successful.

If we keenly observe the *home.routes*,

```
export const router: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
{
    path: 'home', component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
        { path: 'addItem/:groupName', component: AddItemComponent },
        { path: 'addGroup', component: AddGroupComponent },
    ]
}
];
```

it contains a separate "home" route.

```
        path: 'home', component: HomeComponent
```

As this different "home" route also contains the same name "home" in "*app.routes*", that added a lot of confusion.

There are two ways that I can be corrected.

1.
    At first, to release the confusion, change the 'home' route in *home.route* to 'welcome'.

```
         path: 'home', component: HomeComponent,
```

to

```
         path: 'welcome', component: HomeComponent,
```

And then now, fix the actual bug.

```
 { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
```

should be changed to

```
 { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

This will redirectTo home/welcome when loading the homeComponent. And when you click on *addGroup*, it redirects to "/addGroup". So the resultant path would be "/home/welcome/addGroup"

2. The secong way is, change the routes in *home.routes* to

   ```
    export const router: Routes = [     
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent,
        children:[               
          {path: 'addItem/:groupName', component:AddItemComponent},
          {path: 'addGroup', component:AddGroupComponent}
        ]
     }
   ];
   ```

   In this case, the resultant path when routing to addGroup is simply "/home/addGroup"